# QWC2 Generate service configuration ignoring my .qgs file and downloading natural-earth-countries

Tags: qgis, qwc2

I'm trying to get a local qwc2 instance running. I followed the docker quickstart guide (https://github.com/qwc-services/qwc-docker#quick-start) and I'm able to see the demo theme. Following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IafzGxErd_E german language only, but relevant part is from 09:53) I'm saving a qgs file containing a polygon inside the qwc-docker/volumes/config-in/default/qgis_projects/ folder.
Pressing the Generate service configuration button does not however result in the theme showing up. The following is the output of the service configuration:

```
INFO: Config destination: '/srv/qwc_service/config-out/default'
INFO: Searching for projects files in /srv/qwc_service/config-in/default/qgis_projects
INFO: Processing /srv/qwc_service/config-in/default/qgis_projects/qwc2_test_project.qgs
INFO: Written to /data/gen/qwc2_test_project.qgs
INFO: Searching for projects files in /data/scan
INFO: Scanning for thumbnail(natural-earth-countries.png) under /qwc2/assets/img/mapthumbs
INFO: Thumbnail: natural-earth-countries.png could not be found under /qwc2/assets/img/mapthumbs/natural-earth-countries.png
INFO: Adding project /data/scan/natural-earth-countries.qgs
INFO: Downloading GetProjectSettings from http://qwc-qgis-server/ows/qwc_demo
INFO: Reading 'qwc_demo.qgs'
INFO: Downloading GetProjectSettings from http://qwc-qgis-server/ows/scan/natural-earth-countries
INFO: Reading 'scan/natural-earth-countries.qgs'
INFO: Writing 'ogcConfig.json' service config file
INFO: Wrote qwc_demo_edit_lines.ui
INFO: Wrote qwc_demo_edit_points.ui
INFO: Wrote qwc_demo_edit_polygons.ui
INFO: Using WMS GetMap to generate thumbnail for scan/natural-earth-countries
INFO: Copying 'index.html' to tenant dir
INFO: Writing 'mapViewerConfig.json' service config file
INFO: Writing 'featureInfoConfig.json' service config file
INFO: Writing 'printConfig.json' service config file
INFO: Writing 'searchConfig.json' service config file
INFO: Writing 'adminGuiConfig.json' service config file
INFO: Writing 'dbAuthConfig.json' service config file
INFO: Writing 'elevationConfig.json' service config file
INFO: Writing 'mapinfoConfig.json' service config file
INFO: Writing 'permalinkConfig.json' service config file
INFO: Writing 'dataConfig.json' service config file
INFO: Writing 'legendConfig.json' service config file
INFO: The generation of the configuration files was successful
INFO: Configuration files were updated!
INFO: Collecting 'ogc' service permissions
INFO: Collecting 'mapViewer' service permissions
INFO: Collecting 'featureInfo' service permissions
INFO: Collecting 'print' service permissions
INFO: Collecting 'search' service permissions
INFO: Collecting 'adminGui' service permissions
INFO: Collecting 'dbAuth' service permissions
INFO: Collecting 'elevation' service permissions
INFO: Collecting 'mapinfo' service permissions
INFO: Collecting 'permalink' service permissions
INFO: Collecting 'data' service permissions
INFO: Collecting 'legend' service permissions
INFO: Writing 'permissions.json' permissions file
INFO: The generation of the permission files was successful
INFO: permission files were updated!
```

It then shows the natural earth countries example theme but not my project. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Late to answer this but maybe will help someone else.

I would try placing the file in `config-in` volume. The configuration service takes its input from there and deposits the result in `config` volume.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is unclear or incorrect, I ran into the same issue. The correct place to put the project file is volumes/qgs-resources/scan - the generate config button will then process the project. Note that the default is only to look for uncompressed (*.qgs) files rather than the QGIS default save format of *.qgz so make sure you save correctly.